# Why noone else can run my program with MS SolverFoundation namespace in it?

Tags: c#, .net, solver, ms-solver-foundation

I have created a program that uses Microsoft Solver Foundation, so contains a

```
using Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services
```

line around the start.

This required a .Net 4 Framework to be used as target framework. For me, the program runs perfect, but noone else, using the same operation system (Win10), and having a newer framework than .NET 4 can run it. I read up on it, and anyone using Win10 should have .NET 4.5 pre-installed.

Does using a namespace that required me to set up a reference (here, Solver Foundation) need any special care when trying to distribute a program?

I tried to read up on using special namespaces that are not part of the framework originally,but could not find anything on this topic and I'm fairly new to this theoretical part of development.

Comment: I believe that it is [a separate install](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff524499(v=vs.93).aspx).

Comment: Have other people installed Solverfoundation? It seems you need to install that in order to be able to use it.

Comment: Oh god, I have never thought about this, I thought adding a reference to it creates some kind of part in the program that makes it usable without having to install it. But thank you, this is probably the solution!